# Unable to query data between two dates in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.test.find({"date":{$gte:"2017-04-11",$lt:"2017-04-13"}},function(err,doc){
      console.log("date function called");
    res.json(doc);

    console.log(doc);
});
```

code works fine in mongodb and output,but in nodejs the output is empty array.

Comment: First, use `console.log(err)` to see if there is an error

Comment: you should use date as object not as string

Answer (score 1):

> Collections can be queried with find.  The result for the query is actually a *cursor object*. This can be used directly or converted to an array. [Making queries with find()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#making-queries-with-find)
>
> `cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){})` converts the cursor object into an array of all the matching records. Probably the most convenient way to retrieve results but be careful with large datasets as every record is loaded into memory. [toArray](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#toarray)
>
> The mongo shell wraps objects of Date type with the ISODate helper; however, the objects remain of type Date. [Return Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#return-date)

```
var collection = db.collection('test');
collection.find({ "date": { $gte: new Date("2017-04-11"), $lt: new Date("2017-04-13") } })
  .toArray(function (err, doc) {
    console.log("date function called");
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(doc);
      res.json(doc);
    }
  });
```

Comment: i used the above code but it gives  
ReferenceError: ISODate is not defined

Comment: i got a output like this : server running on port 9000
date function called
[]

Comment: @VijaykumarVijay use `new Date`, not `ISODate`

Comment: @VijaykumarVijay Is your collection named `test`?

Comment: i used new Date and collection name is test itself. It works fine in mongoshell but in nodejs i got like this ,date function called [] empty array